# Loops within loops and assigning variables in a deep loop

Tags: ruby, variables, loops, closures

I have a block of code like so (this is the working version)

```
@full_user_schedule[0].attributes.each do |event_name, attending|
   if attending
     sessions_hash.each do |id, name|
       event_name = event_name.sub(name, id.to_s) if event_name.include? name 
     end
     @user_schedule.merge!(event_name => attending)
   end
end
```

When I tried to set the variable `event_id` within the `sessions_hash.each` statement, I could not get it to assign outside of that loop (got an unknown variable warning). I'd like to know why this is so, and how to circumvent it.

Below is an example of what was failing (event though the log showed the variable was being set correctly), I did not have access to it outside of the loop in which it was created.

```
@full_user_schedule[0].attributes.each do |event_name, attending|
   if attending
     sessions_hash.each do |id, name|
       event_id = event_name.sub(name, id.to_s) if event_name.include? name 
     end
     @user_schedule.merge!(event_id => attending)
   end
end
```

I tried to explicitly return `event_id`, but that exited the loop. What am I not understanding?

Answer (score 4):

A block is really a sort of anonymous function, so it has its own scope, but it does have access to variables in the surrounding scopes.

Just initialize `event_id` before the block starts, making it an element of the parent method.

```
event_id = nil
@full_user_schedule[0].attributes.each do |event_name, attending|
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In the second code example, event_id is created and assigned within the block passed by `sessions_hash.each`. It only exists within that block and can't be accessed from code outside the block. This is called scope.

In the first example, you are assigning to event_name, which is defined in the block passed to `@full_user_schedule[0].attributes.each` and the rest of the code is also contained in this block, so it's always in scope.

I don't full understand what you are trying to accomplish here, but it seems that this would work:

```
@full_user_schedule[0].attributes.each do |event_name, attending|
  if attending
     sessions_hash.each do |id, name|
       event_id = event_name.sub(name, id.to_s) if event_name.include? name 
     end
     @user_schedule.merge!(event_id => attending)
   end
end
```

I moved the line `@user_schedule...` so it's in the same scope as `event_id`